# Why does Snappy Driver Installer recommend so many driver updates?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-update

I have a Surface Book 2 that is fully up to date according to Windows Update. However, I've been experiencing performance issues. Long story short, I found some people recommending [Snappy Driver Installer](https://sdi-tool.org/). When I run it, it recommends I update a whole slew of drivers:

[image]

Why is this? How can it be that so many drivers are out of date when Windows Update says otherwise? Basically, I'm not sure whether I should trust this or not.

Comment: I do not trust Snappy Driver. Windows 10 is leagues better than any free software for managing your device drivers.

Comment: Everything visible on this screen is just one update: The Intel INF Update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're having performance issues, the problem is rarely drivers.  The symptom of driver problems is generally that the hardware doesn't work, certain features aren't available, or you encounter hardware bugs in operation.

These driver installer utilities tend to be somewhat of a scam.  There isn't really a problem you need them to fix.  They fill a market hole for people who think they always need the "latest" drivers.  These utilities identify most of the drivers in your system and claim they all need updating or there is a better one available.  That makes them look valuable.  But the vast majority of what they report is just wrong.

Many of the "updates" they report are actually older drivers than what is installed.  They are often the wrong drivers, or a variant of what is installed, like the vendor's generic equivalent of the OEM driver on your system, which has been optimized for your hardware.  Letting it do wholesale replacement of your drivers is more likely to create issues you don't currently have than to solve any problem.  Even if it doesn't actively harm the system's functioning, you won't see any improvement in performance.

When I used Windows, these utilities were all the rage.  I discovered the reality first-hand with many different popular utilities.  I didn't have any problems, I just wanted to make sure I had the latest and best drivers.  Initially, I just let them run and do their thing, and they created problems that I hadn't had.  Then I started scrutinizing their recommendations and discovered that virtually everything they reported was either unnecessary or actually a bad recommendation.

Investigating online, it turned out that the uselessness of the utilities was widely known.  There is plenty of information online, but these articles by How-To Geek cover the matter pretty well:

- [When Do You Need to Update Your Drivers?](https://www.howtogeek.com/98465/htg-explains-when-do-you-need-to-update-your-drivers/)
- [Never Download a Driver-Updating Utility; They’re Worse Than Useless](https://www.howtogeek.com/198758/never-download-a-driver-updating-utility-theyre-worse-than-useless/)
- [The Only Safe Way to Update Your Hardware Drivers on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/233115/the-only-way-to-safely-update-your-hardware-drivers-on-windows/)

As a general rule, if the hardware is functioning properly, don't change drivers.  The only time to look at driver replacement is if your driver gets corrupted, or you encounter a problem of hardware not working correctly.

If Windows Update or your hardware manufacturer notifies you of a driver update, consider installing it.  But look at what they claim the update does.  If it is being offered to fix a problem for hardware you don't have, there's no benefit to updating.

If you do update a driver other than a generic Windows driver offered by Windows Update, the best source is your computer manufacturer's web site.  The OEM driver will be optimized for your hardware.  If they no longer offer the driver you need, try the hardware component manufacturer's web site.

In general, you should rarely need to update or change any driver if the hardware is not malfunctioning.  The main exception would be if a newer driver is needed to support features or functionality not offered by the original driver.

Performance issues are almost always something else.

Comment: The only drivers I would ever update are the GPU (which is handled by AMD/NVIDIA software) and Intel RST drivers.  Depending on if I had the hardware I might update the LAN drivers, some network adapters, only support specific versions of Windows 10 (KIller Networking).  I can't think of a single driver other than those 3 that would ever need to be updated after I installed the initial version (unless they stopped working).  If that happens i would go directly to the manufacture website, skip the often buggy driver applications, and install only what I needed for the device to work.

Comment: Another reason to update if the drivers have security vulnerabilities. The driver may be running well but it may make your PC vulnerable.

Comment: Ancient wisdom: If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but feel like I have to say this:

- Most driver updaters are some sort of scam, but not this one. It's totally free, no paid features, constantly updated & remains free, open source forever.
- I personally do not consider this tool as a normal driver updater. It provides more information about drivers that a normal user would need. For example, you can install old versions, select which one to use among many drivers available for one "module". Which suggests me, if I want to customize my PC as much as I can for performance, I can skip something like Touchpad, get a better latency with High Precision Event Timer ( not available, not signed ), and see which one I actually need & choose the driver that is expected to be better
- Back to your question. I don't know if almost all of them are just update for only one thing ( someone said The Intel INF update ), or they're actually different modules but have a similar name ( which is what I guessed, but not totally sure ). So, what I recommend is, if you need a working device, just use Windows Update, and if you want something cool and advanced, go ahead for this one and KNOW WHAT TO DO.

Also, you should click "Download Indexes only", else it will start downloading alot of other stuffs, I don't know but some of them are not meant to be used / used by your PC. Tick "Expert mode" and hover the option to know what do the tags mean.

( My English is shit, but I really hope this helps and clears up the visible confusion )

Comment: I upvoted this "comment" answer because we value your opinion. SO allows for new users to answer but not to comment? Crazy.

Answer (score -2):

in my experience the whole thing with drivers come like:
a) Device is working
b) Device is not working
c) Blue screen here, blue screen there, blue screen everywhere...

personally i don't trust this kind of programs, they suggest tonz of drivers while trust me, 
1) the majority of them are outdated, 
2) the quality of the drivers isn't guaranteed (will they work for real? are there any serous bugs or security bugs that coming with them?)
3) probably Microsoft drivers are mostly basic drivers with some exceptions i guess though they work fine... i am not sure where these drivers are coming from

also keep one of the golden rules in computers "If it's working, leave it be, if not and you have no other option kick it's azz until it says "please no more""and same goes for drivers too, if the default drivers are working, just don't change them... and since you know what hardware your computer has, using manufacturer drivers imho is the best option.

and since you mentioned that you have a poor performance drivers are the last thing i would check and in your case since as far i see your hardware is in overall GREAT for running windows 10 i would check

a) software running, services etc that could end up in a slow performance.
b) Temperature of System (through BIOS) laptops etc, when temperature goes high as a hardware security they tend to force hardware working slower for not getting in higher temperature.
c)your disk drive health etc
c) how RAM is working.